# Error can't read .env file on my CLI program

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have created cli program with commander package but I faced an error.
I try to run my program outside my program folder, it got an error like this on the terminal:

> home/bimodwilaksono/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/getuser-cli: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"dotenv"'

> /home/bimodwilaksono/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/getuser-cli: line 1: `require("dotenv").config();'

This is my source code:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const program = require("commander");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const db = mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const listUsers = () => {
  User.find().then((Users) => {
    console.log(Users);
    console.log(`${Users.length} Users`);
    mongoose.disconnect();
  });
};

//Program

//List Command
program
  .command("list")
  .alias("l")
  .description("List all users")
  .action(() => listUsers());

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Apparently, when I run my program outside its folder it can't read ***environment variable***. But if I don't use ***environment variable***, my program is work. For example like this :

```
const db = mongoose.connect("ThisistheConnectionString");
```

What I have to do to run program which has ***environment variable*** to work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My need is what i have to do to make my CLI program work with environment variables when I try to run at the outside its folder? Because when I don't use environment variables, my program is work. I am sorry with my English, I hope you can understand.